# GZIPing HTML in PHP stops Google Adsense adverts showing

Tags: php, gzip, adsense

Attempting to reduce a ~60kb index page to ~10kb using GZIP in PHP. I have achieved success apart from my Google Adsense adverts do not show.

For your consideration I have included 2 live examples of the same page:

- **Default Content-Encoding:** http://openmicfinder.co.uk/index.php (Adverts display)
- **GZIP Content-Encoding:** http://openmicfinder.co.uk/index2.php (Adverts Not displaying)

The code I am using is as follows (You may recognise it from this post: [PHP Manual GZip Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699020/php-manual-gzip-encoding)):

```
function _compress($data) {
    $supportsGzip = strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip' ) !== false;

    if ( $supportsGzip ) {
        $content = gzencode( trim( preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $data ) ), 9);
    } else {
        $content = $data;
    }

    $offset = 60 * 60;
    $expire = "expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT";

    header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
    header("content-type: text/html; charset: UTF-8");
    header("cache-control: must-revalidate");
    header( $expire );
    header( 'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $content ) );
    header('Vary: Accept-Encoding');

    echo $content;
}

ob_start();
include("index_standard.php");
$contents = ob_get_clean(); 
ob_end_flush();
_compress($contents);
```

This has me proper stumped because other Javascript is unaffected.

*As a side-note. I would love to understand (and remedy) this bug but if not possible I would consider changing my ad slots to an asynchronous loading method as a backup plan.*

Answer (score 1):

Before your `sesion_start()`

```
if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); else ob_start();
include("index_standard.php");
ob_flush();
```

Comment: Thank you! That is a much more up-to-date method