# php image data compress with ob_gzhandler not working

Tags: php, zlib, image-compression

When I'm trying to use `readfile` with `ob_gzhandler` I'm getting in browser:

> Content Encoding Error

my code is

```
function enableCompression()
{
    $ok = ob_gzhandler('', PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_START);
    if ($ok === FALSE) {
        return FALSE; // not allowed
    }

    if (function_exists('ini_set')) {
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression_level', '6');
    }
    ob_start('ob_gzhandler', 1);
    return TRUE;
}

enableCompression(); //returns TRUE

$file = "pathto/default.png";
$info = @getimagesize($file);
header('Content-type: ' . $info['mime']);

readfile($file);
exit;
```

When I comment `header('Content-type: ' . $info['mime']);` line, I see image data like this in browser

> �PNG  IHDR��J�TPLTE��ސ�������������ؑ��������vvv�����䀀�� ...."

**Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to compress image data with usage ob_gzhandler?**

**PS:** zlib is installed all is working, other website data is normally outputed. Only compressed  image resizer is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the mis-encoding issue you're seeing is related to the fact you're calling `ob_gzhandler()` directly. It's not intended to be called directly. If you need to see if ob_gzhandler is supported you can test [like this](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php#91685):

```
if(!ob_start('ob_gzhandler')) {
    die('ob_gzhandler not supported');
}
```

After making that change the `Content-Type` header was fixed and the image displayed correctly. The content didn't come out compressed though.

It appears that if you send the `Content-Type: image/png` header after you start the output buffer it causes ob_gzhandler to not compress the output buffer. This worked for me:

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
readfile('test.png');
ob_end_flush();
```

While this didn't:

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
header('Content-type: image/png');
readfile("test.png");
ob_end_flush();
```

That being said, normally it's a bad idea to compress PNG files (or JPEG, GIF, etc) since they're already compressed and probably can't be compressed very much better. Is there a reason you're trying to double compress a PNG file?

Comment: Yes solution with headers before worked for me thanks. Actually i wanted to give try for images compression to see if it optimal for my case or no and the result is NO :) compression increases image load time 2 times from 80ms to 160ms

Answer (score 0):

You may need a content encoding header

> header('Content-Encoding: gzip');

Otherwise, you are sending gzip'ed data, that you are telling the browser is "just an image", so it's trying to draw "just the image" and not ungzipping first

Here is a similar related post: [PHP Manual GZip Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699020/php-manual-gzip-encoding).

Comment: I have that header set