# Using ajax to request gzip compressed data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm making an $.ajax call to an endpoint that is responding with gzipped content.  For the life of me I cannot figure out how to get it so that the browser sees it that way and can uncompress it.  The ajax request I'm making is

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://my.server/compressed.html',
  method: 'post',
  beforeSend: function (request) {
    //request.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "compress, gzip");
  },
  success: function (data) {
    console.log('success', data);
  },
  error: function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    console.log('error', textStatus, errorThrown);
  }
});
```

When the success function is triggered, data is just showing as

```
���1 �PDѽ�:ޏ�$�+A,D����*��w%���T�9�g���1G����h�6��'�nۖ\����~�%^
```

As you can see I've tried setting the 'Accept-Encoding' head but the error I'm getting when I do that is `Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Encoding"`.  I've tried setting headers on the server side as described in this answer [PHP Manual GZip Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699020/php-manual-gzip-encoding)
but that didn't help me either.  I just don't know what I'm missing.  What do I need to include in the $.ajax() request (and possibly the server response) to get it so that the success callback has the uncompressed data?

thnx,
Christoph

Answer (score 2):

derp.  I totally missed (and thought I had) the header

```
header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
```

Adding that and viola, it works.  I'm not bright sometimes...

thnx,
Christoph